# Alert message onfocus

Tags: javascript

I don't get it. Why does this alert on page load? How to make it alert only "onfocus"?

```
<input id="mail" name="E-post" value="E-post">
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    function onfocusFunction() {
        alert('Why!?');
    }
    var myMail = document.getElementById('mail');
    myMail.onfocus = onfocusFunction();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With parenthesis `()`, you are calling `onfocusFunction` function and assigning `undefined` to `myMail.onfocus`:

```
myMail.onfocus = undefined;
```

as your `onfocusFunction` function does not return anything.

Without parenthesis, you will have `onfocusFunction` object, which should be assigned to `.onfocus`:

```
myMail.onfocus = onfocusFunction;  //No parenthesis before ';'
```

**UPDATE:** If you want to pass parameters either, then try like this:

```
function onfocusFunction(param1,param2) {
    return function(){
       alert(param1+":"+param2);
    };
}
var myMail = document.getElementById('mail');
myMail.onfocus = onfocusFunction("value1","value2");
```

Then when `onfocus` event will be triggered you will see `"value1:value2"` as an alert.

Comment: That works. But what if I want to pass in variables to the function?

Comment: onfocus = function(){onfocusFunction(param1,param2 etc);};

Comment: Thanks for showing the solution! I will accept it as an answer :) But I still don't understand how window.onload can trigger the function to alert on page load, before the input is clicked...?

Comment: @user1087110 with `()` parenthesis after function's name `fname()`, you call `fname` function. Without `()`, you get `fname` object, which should be assigned to `onfocus`.Does that make sense ?

Comment: Thanks! That was good to know! I don't fully understand "you get fname object, which should be assigned to onfocus".

Comment: @user1087110 functions are objects in javascript, and by `myMail.onfocus=fname`, you assign `fname` object/function to `onfocus` property.

Answer (score 0):

when you type `myMail.onfocus = onfocusFunction();`

1. your are calling `onfocusFunction()` and
2. assigning its return value to `myMail.onfocus`

( in this case the return value is null );

let say :

```
 function onfocusFunction() {
        alert('Why!?');
return "ok";
    }
```

so `myMail.onfocus` will be the string 'ok' instead of a function

you can use Engineer's Solution

or try :

```
myMail.onfocus = function(){alert("why")};
```